# Can I generate proxy objects for WCF service library using scriptmanager?

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf, proxy-classes

I have used the AJAX Enabled WCF Service template from within a web application. By adding a Service reference to the scriptmanager, some client objects are generated allowing me to easily consume the service. My question is can I do anything like that when I use a WCF Service Library? I added the project to my solution and in my web app I added a service reference to the service. This is where I get a bit stuck. What do I do now to allow consuming the service from the client.

Comment: Bueller?? Bueller??? Anybody??? Lol :)

Answer (score 0):

So, just to consume wcf service, you have to use "svcutil" app from VS pack to generate o proxy class, which is very simple in usage.